# Error Message when Deploying updated WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a web service that was running the beta version of WebApi and we upgraded to the latest version, do to some compilation problems we were getting.

When we deploy the service I am receiving the below error message.

```
Method not found: 'Void System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.set_SerializerSettings(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings)'.
```

I believe the problem is that is it pulling the wrong version of the assembly from the GAC, however this doesn't make sense since I made sure that I set all references to copy local and they have a newer version, so it should be pulling the local version of the assemblies, not the ones in the GAC.

I know the logical thing to do would be to update the version of WebAPI on the production server, however there are other services running on there that are still using the beta version, so I don't want to disturb them.

I was wondering if someone could help me with this issue or describe a solution for the below error message.

Comment: have you checked the deployable bin folder to ensure the expected assembly versions are there?

Comment: Yes I have checked them and they are the versions that I am expecting to see. Thanks.

Comment: Closer examination revealed
`[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.set_SerializerSettings(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings)'.]
   Poject.Web.Api.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() +0`

Comment: Below are the contents of that method. Is this the source of my problem?
`protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            var jSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = jSettings;
        }`

Comment: I ended up just updating to the release version of WebAPI and everything worked correctly.